# Breeze InlineCount on Navigational without expanding

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

How can I get an [InlineCount](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_inlineCount) on Navigational without expanding the Navigational Property.
All I need is the count and I don't want the overhead of bringing down the child entities.

I would like to mimic something like this SQL psuedo-code:

```
select 
    *, 
    (select count(*) from Child where ParentId = Parent.Id) as ChildCount
from Parent 
where id = 305
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a named query method on the server like this, ( with your custom count logic inside)

```
[HttpGet]
public Int32 OrdersCountForCustomer(string companyName) {
  var customer =
    MyContextProvider.Context.Customers.Include("Orders").Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith(companyName)).First();
  return customer.Orders.Count;
}
```

and then query it from the client like this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("OrdersCountForCustomer").withParameters({ companyName: "IBM" });
em.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
    var count = parseInt(data.results[0]);
});
```

Comment: this would be neat - var qry = EntityQuery.From("Customer").navCount("Orders").where("Id", "==", 1); and results = [ results = CustomerObject, navcounts.Orders = 22 ]

Answer (score 1):

**You do not need a special "OrdersCountForCustomer" endpoint for this purpose!**

Instead, you can issue a query that returns 0 results.

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from('Orders')
   .where('customerId', 'eq', theId)
   .take(0)
   .inlineCount(true)
   .using(em).execute()
   .then(function (data) {
       var count = data.inlineCount;
   });
```

I realize this might resolve to two SQL requests on the data tier (one is the query for zero records and the other for the count) and that such requests *might be* less scalable. But it's simple, general purpose, extensible, and probably not the performance problem in practice that speculation leads you to fear.

Comment: Say I need list of Customers and want a count of the navigational props (arrays) Orders, Purchases, Addresses.I want to return this alongside the list of Customers. I could query separately and store as a hashtable, and have a VM function to bindto, but it seems I often want to return data with the entity results.  DTO seems the right way to do this, but don't want to lose the tracking of the EM.For this particular problem I thought there might be a neat way to count the number of elements in a navaigational array - from("Customers").where("Name", startswith", "A").countButDontExpand("Orders")

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing like that in BreezeJS and I don't think there is anything like that on the server either. If you need that, I agree with you ... you really will have to add a specialized endpoint with that counts dto.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("OrdersCountForCustomer").withParameters      ({companyName: "IBM" }).inlineCount(true);
em.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
var count = data.inlineCount;
});
```